# OutOfMemoryError in Android while using OnClickItemListener in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Please help me i am facing this problem. Here I am pasting my code:

I have tried but not able to find out what I am missing. I am using two fragments two display the list. Now i want to change the list data in second fragment when user click on the first list item. By default zero position index will be selected to display the data in second list. I am using custom array adapter to display the list in both fragments.Please help me out guys.Thanks for considering. Here I am pasting my code where I am getting this error :

Complete code : [onItemClickListener between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683593/onitemclicklistener-between-two-fragments)

Second Fragment:

```
 public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
    private static HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> imgBitmapUrls;
    public  ListView listOfProducts;
    ProductInterface productInterfaceForProductList;
    private static String jsonPorductsCategoryListResponse;
    private static String cookie;
    private static String[] productImgPath;
    private static String[] nids;
    private static String[] title;
    private static String[] tids;
    private static String tid;
    private static HashMap<Integer, String> productListImagePath;
    DisplayProductListArrayAdapter productListAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View fragProListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_category_list, container,
                    false);
         listOfProducts =(ListView) fragProListView .findViewById(R.id.productCategorylistView);
        return fragProListView;
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        productInterfaceForProductList = (ProductInterface) getActivity();



        GetDataFromJsonResponse dataResponse = new GetDataFromJsonResponse();
        dataResponse.dataForCustomArrayAdapter();
        productListAdapter = new DisplayProductListArrayAdapter(
                    getActivity(), title,
                    imgBitmapUrls);
         listOfProducts.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
         listOfProducts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
     static ProductListFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
         ProductListFragment productListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
         productListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            cookie = bundle.getString(BsharpConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES);
            tids = bundle.getStringArray(BsharpConstant.TAXONOMY_TID);
            return productListFragment;
        }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public class GetDataFromJsonResponse{
        public void dataForCustomArrayAdapter(){
            if(getTid()==null){
                tid = tids[0];
                }           
        jsonPorductsCategoryListResponse = WebserviceBsharpUtil.
                    callWebServicesGetProductsList(cookie, getTid());
        nids = ProductCategoryIds.parseJSONResponseToGetTidsOfProducts(
                jsonPorductsCategoryListResponse,
                BsharpConstant.PRODUCT_NODE_ID);
        title = ProductCategoryIds.parseJSONResponseToGetTidsOfProducts(
                jsonPorductsCategoryListResponse,
                BsharpConstant.PRODUCT_TITLE);
        productImgPath = ProductCategoryIds.parseJSONResponseToGetTidsOfProducts(
                jsonPorductsCategoryListResponse,
                BsharpConstant.PRODUCT_IMAGE);
                productListImagePath = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                for(int i =0;i<productImgPath.length;i++){
                    productListImagePath.put(i, productImgPath[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(productListImagePath);
        imgBitmapUrls = productInterfaceForProductList
                .DownloadImages(productListImagePath);
        }
    }


    public class DisplayProductListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context context;
        HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> prodctImgs;
        String[] proCategoryNames;
        HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>bitUrls;
        DisplayProductListArrayAdapter(Context c,
                String[] listCategory, HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> imgUrls) {
            super(c,
                    R.layout.products_list_single_layout,
                    R.id.productCategoryName, listCategory);
            this.context = c;
            this.prodctImgs = imgUrls;
            this.proCategoryNames = listCategory;
            this.bitUrls = imgUrls;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); 
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_list_single_layout, parent, false);
            ImageView productCategoryImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.productImageId);
            Bitmap bitmap = imgBitmapUrls.get(position);
            // productCategoryImage.setFocusable(false);
            TextView productCategoryName = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.productName);
            productCategoryImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            productCategoryName.setText(proCategoryNames[position]);
            return row;
        }
    }

    public void clickedProductCategoryIdByProductCategoryFragment(String tid){
        ProductListFragment.setTid(tid);    
    }

    public static String getTid() {
        return tid;
    }

    public static void setTid(String tid) {
        ProductListFragment.tid = tid;
    }
}
```

Here is logcat:

```
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:599)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.imagedownload.ImageDownloader.getBitmapFromURL(ImageDownloader.java:60)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.ProductListActivity.DownloadImages(ProductListActivity.java:119)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.ProductListFragment$GetDataFromJsonResponse.dataForCustomArrayAdapter(ProductListFragment.java:100)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.ProductListFragment.clickedProductCategoryIdByProductCategoryFragment(ProductListFragment.java:146)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.ProductListActivity.clickedProductCategory(ProductListActivity.java:131)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.lenovo.bsharp.ProductCategoryFragment.onItemClick(ProductCategoryFragment.java:93)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-20 11:24:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 11:29:38.997: I/Process(937): Sending signal. PID: 937 SIG: 9
12-20 11:29:39.917: E/Trace(952): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

This is my bit map code:

```
 try {
            System.out.printf("src", src);
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            System.out.printf("Bitmap", "returned");
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.printf("Exception", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: please show us the logcat (I will shorten it in further requests pslc)

Comment: Please check it i have pasted it above

Comment: Your images are too large.  There are many answers on StackOverflow for how to scale them down when you load them.

Comment: check- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: Please check the android doc for this error: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because of your bitmap implementation in getView() method in your adapter

Try this

[CreatScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Here is example

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. As you ca see the above code i am using onItemclickListener and list will get change in second fragment and by default first list would be display. How can i improve my code. Thanks for all of you for support.

Answer (score 2):

Handling bitmaps in a listview can be tricky. You may want to consider using a third party library that can help you manage bitmaps in the list to avoid Out of memory issues. Try [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: how i can use this library as i mentioned in my post i am very new about this. Could you please tell me ? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest browsing through the link, downloading the sample app, and see how the library is being used.