# add a new button from another fragment class

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments

My problem is that I have two classes that extend Fragment.Now I have a button(its name is save) in 1 fragment class.I want to add a new button in another fragment class when 'save' button is clicked.I know I need to have an onClickListener for the 'save' button but I don't know how to go further from there.I also want an onClickListener for the new created button.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post code.  This is pretty vague as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

use interface to communicate from one fragment to another.

follow the below link. You will find out something:

[onItemClickListener between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683593/onitemclicklistener-between-two-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on the relationships between fragments, whether they are nested etc.

1) Use SharedPreferences.  That means you would write to the apps defaultSharedPreferences some flag which says "save has been pressed", and then in the other fragment any time you call createView you would check this flag in preferences.  IF save has been pressed you would then show the button.

This approach has a few issues though depending on how long you want to show this button for, if it should be shown forever etc.

2)  The interface approach mentioned is valid, but it has coupling issues, and may not be suited to the framework you have in place.

3)  Broadcasts - you can use intents and send messages between fragments.  This runs into some vaugeness issues (You need to be careful when documenting broadcasts and intents) and can be somewhat opaque to other readers.

Comment: Can you please write down how can I use intents and broadcasts messages for communication between fragments ?